# Web Server for Android

Tags: android, web-development, web-server

I need an android app, which is similar to WAMP server on Windows machine, where I can open my php files.

Reason I need this is because am a web developer, I often get emails to alter some codes, while I'm traveling, and I've a tab so its comfortable to edit these files using Droid Editor, but the issue is, I alter the file, mail it back, if there's some issue, the concerned person pings me back with the error message and this goes on ...

So if I get a Web Server for my phone, where I can open the php files using localhost as I do it on my laptop, which should have..

- Apache (Or similar)
- PHP (with Extensions)
- MySQL
- PHP MyAdmin like interface

---

As commented, if anyone needs clarification of my work process, *(which I don't think is relevant anyways as I want the web server on my phone)*, so the process I used to do, is - client/concerned person mails the file, I edit the file if I can from my editor, and I send it back to the person where he deploys the php file live on the website.

Now these files are generally contact us pages, single page websites etc, now I can handle these nicely from my phone, but for some reason, I want to test some code of php, I used services like codeviper etc, to check the output of my code, so I decided to have a web server on my phone so that I don't have to visit these websites for small requirements.

Comment: It might be quicker to just set up a WAMP or LAMP server somewhere else, then connect to it through SSH or FTP. DroidEdit has FTP/SFTP support, at least in the pro version. You could edit the files directly on your test server, then move to production when you've ironed the bugs out.  Having to send in changes by mail (I hope to Jeeves that's email, not postal mail) sounds painful.

Comment: Or, you know, use a laptop?

Comment: @WanderNauta Correct, but I do not have access to ftp always, the credentials aren't shared, only relevant files are shared.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit in your question how that works? How can you work on a site you can only see little bits of?

Comment: @WanderNauta its not always the site, sometimes, I've simple contact pages programmed in php, so issues like mail goes wrong, or header issues etc, I can manage to program those without testing, so when they are deployed on server, the users can test, I will edit my question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bit Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb) seems to be that.

- Lighttpd
- PHP
- MySQL
- PHPMyAdmin

It costs about 2USD though.

There is a [free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweblite) with a documented limitation "Cannot access MySQL database", which sounds like a big limitation.

Comment: This looks promising, I would wait until someone posts a nice web server app for free, if not I'll buy this or [ksweb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb) - looks nice to me

Comment: Also, the free version would suffice as I hardly get any db related files, this will save my time to test the php code online...

Answer (score 1):

Bit Web Server (Free) would suffice my requirements as I mainly need the PHP testing on my phone, apart from that, MySQL and PHP MyAdmin are like bonuses, and I would consider them to be mandatory once I am comfortable handling the PHP systems on my phone and eventually I'll buy the software.

But if someone needs any alternative to Bit Web Server, I downloaded [KSWEB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb) on my phone, and they are providing a fully functional software TO TRY for 5 days, and this software has all of what the WAMP and MAMP provides. The interface is friendly, and does the job, edited few files for testing and works for me.

The bad part is that it's premium only.

From Google Playstore :

> KSLabs team wants to bring to your attention KSWEB – a suite of web
>   developer for Android platform. It consists of: a web server, a PHP
>   programming language, a database MySQL and msmtp for sendmail support.
>   This suite allows you to organize a platform for running and debugging
>   Web applications (sites) in your Android device and You don't need a
>   root access to run KSWEB. Otherwise, you can start your web server on
>   80 port. A user friendly interface of KSWeb and our online support
>   leads you to realization of all your web projects. This software is
>   shareware. You have a trial period of 5 days. The price of KSWEB PRO
>   is $3.99. The price of KSWEB Standard is $2.99.

**KS Web Features :**

- lighttpd server v1.4.34 (SSL)
- nginx v1.5.10 (SSL)
- PHP v5.4.24 (SSL)
- MySQL v5.1.62
- msmtp v1.4.31
- Web Interface v1.1
- KSWEBFTP v1.0